# RewriteRule redirecting to URL not found on server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect subdomains ending in /en or /en/ to ?locale=en_US the same for domains ending in /es or /es/.

My problem is that for some reason my code works well for all domains except /es/ (with a slash). When I go to http://momemi.com/easee/es/ it takes me to http://momemi.com/es and I get the message: "The requested URL /es was not found on this server.". Any idea why I might be being redirected there just on the /es/ URL?

This is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /easee/

# Lenguajes soportados (aparte de inglés)
RewriteRule ^en[/]?$ ?locale=en_US [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^es[/]?$ ?locale=es_ES [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your rules look fine. Most likely you have some other rules or a code issue. Test this in chrome dev tool and see what redirects are you getting in `Net` tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing using [this testing tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) and the following worked for me using a backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)en[/]?$ $1?locale=en_US [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)es[/]?$ $1?locale=es_ES [L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps.